# How do you loop through a vector of data frame names in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse

I'd like to loop through a vector of data frame names in R. Below is roughly what I'm trying to do. The last code chunk doesn't quite work. I've tried putting "j" in brackets, using a combination of `get()` and `paste0()`, but no luck yet.

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars

blue <- starwars %>% 
        filter(eye_color=="blue")
brown <- starwars %>% 
         filter(eye_color=="brown")

df_set <- Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())

#This is what I want to do for one data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(blue)) {
  if (is.na(blue$mass[i])) {
    blue$mass[i] <- 10000
  }
}

#How do I loop through all data frames as specified in vector df_set?
for (j in df_set) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(j)) {
    if (is.na(j$mass[i])) {
      j$mass[i] <- 10000
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The actual use case is significantly more complex and has a structure such that within a nested for loop, looping over either a list or vector of names of data frames is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` to loop over the `list` of datasets and use the standard tidyverse functions to replace the `NA` with value

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df_set_new <- map(df_set, ~ .x %>%
                  mutate(mass = replace_na(mass, 10000)))
```

#### data

```
df_set <- list(blue, brown)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a loop follow the great advice of **@GregorThomas**, store your dataframes in a list like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
blue <- starwars %>% 
  filter(eye_color=="blue")
brown <- starwars %>% 
  filter(eye_color=="brown")

df_set <- Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())

#List
List <- list(blue,brown)
names(List) <- df_set

#Loop
for (i in df_set) 
{
  List[[i]]$mass <- ifelse(is.na(List[[i]]$mass),10000,List[[i]]$mass)
}
```

Some checks:

Before you had:

```
sum(List$blue$mass)
[1] NA
```

After the loop you will have:

```
sum(List$blue$mass)
[1] 71038.2
```

If you need the dataframes in environment you can use:

```
#Code
list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

And the new dataframes will have the changes you made in the loop.